# Need to reduce the timeout period for a route in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

Within expressjs is there a way I can set the timeout limit per route.

I have some routes that may take 30-45 seconds to process (A large amount of tasks)

And then other routes that if it takes longer than 5 seconds I want it to time out.

I guess I am asking is there a way to globally set the timeout limit on requests and is there a way to do it individually on routes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222467/express-js-http-request-timeout

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the built-in connect-timeout middleware:

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/timeout.html

```
var connectTimeout = require('connect-timeout');

var timeout = connectTimeout({ time: 10000 });
var longTimeout = connectTimeout({ time: 45000 });

app.use(timeout); // you can set a global timeout value
app.get('/some/route', longTimeout, yourHandler); // or you can set per-route timeouts
```