# expressjs HTTP GET sends error: "ETIMEDOUT", 200

Tags: node.js, http, express, connect-timeout

In Express.js, by making some HTTP GET requests, if the operation on the server takes more than 5 seconds, it sends an error: "ETIMEDOUT" (status 200).

How can I solve this?

I tried to use connect-timeout middleware:

```
var longTimeout = require('connect-timeout')({ time: 20000 })
```

but without result.

Comment: Do you want this in express middleware or as http.get request ?

Comment: I want server to send the data even after 5000 ms passed, client side is awaiting.

Comment: Express doesn't time out by itself. What exactly is the operation that takes more than 5 seconds, and are you sure it isn't the client that is timing out the request because it's taking too long?

Comment: Are you using the middleware correctly ? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408573/need-to-reduce-the-timeout-period-for-a-route-in-expressjs

Comment: @user568109 Yes I referenced to the same example.

Comment: @robertklep yes I extended timeout on the client, and I said that the server responses with status 200 and data: {error: “ETIMEDOUT”}

Comment: @WHITECOLOR and I'm saying that Express doesn't generate such errors by itself. You're not explaining what *the operation* is, so hard to debug this issue...

Comment: @robertklep the operation is request and manipulations with MongoDB. Operation with DB completes in more then 5 sec. It completes successfully but response with error is sent before.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/42bc461cc15550b58d3d) showing that Express doesn't generate timeouts if an operation (in this case, `setTimeout`) takes more than 5 seconds.