# What is the default http timeout in NestJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, nestjs

Our backend depend on result from a cloud function. The limit on a cloud function is 15 minutes, but what is the default timeout for a default configured NestJS server request ? It seems that the server request timeouts on our client.

Can you point me do the docs where it's explained or how it can be configured.

Comment: From what I'm reading on Nest.js site, it uses Express under the hood by default.  So check [Express.js HTTP request timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7242428/691711).  Which points you to [`node.js#server.requestTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#serverrequesttimeout)

Comment: I tested it, the controller waits until 120 seconds and then gives me a 408 error. so I think the timeout is 120 seconds, not 300 seconds as in the doc above.